# How to set Color for selected Text in java?

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtextarea

Please any one help for set the color for selected text only... I has Create a Simple Text Editor... But, I can't set the color for selected text contents... once ,I has select the color it will affect the whole text area instead of selected area.

Please Help Any One,

Thanks in Advance.

```
for Example :
```

[image][image]

Now I select the Kumar only..So,will select the color for that selected text only..But,my problem is change the color for unselected text also..

How to resolve it???????

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you give some code?

Comment: Can you provide some code, and... money?

Comment: Look for the methods `setSelectedTextColor`and `setSelectionColor` in the documentation for JTextComponent.

Comment: Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose a color", Color.blue);                                                         This code only i am using now...It will return the selected color..Now,i want to set this color for seleted text only..ple help me

Comment: Code, code, code it is always about it, please if you have tried anything do not provide us just with a plain text.

Comment: @jpw i have tried that API..But,that is not working fine..

Comment: **setForeground** this API will change the whole foreground color of JTextArea

Answer (score 2):

With what component do you display your text?
If it is JTextArea, then it is not possible.
You need a component that allows different styles. For example a StyledDocument in a JTextPane.
For more information see [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

Comment: +1 for the link to the tutorial, But there is a better example if you look at the section on `Text Component Features`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Selected Color Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JTextArea area = new JTextArea("Text for test...", 5, 10);
    frame.add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton button = new JButton("Select Color");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(frame, "Colors",
                    Color.BLUE);
            area.selectAll();
            // area.setSelectedTextColor(color); // color of selected text
            area.setSelectionColor(color); // background of selected text
            area.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    });
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

---

[image]