# How to change selected text color in java?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jeditorpane, textcolor

I need to change selected text color in `editorPane` in java.
I tried using this code,

```
txt_body.setSelectedTextColor(Color.yellow);
```

but font color did not change.How do I solve this ???

Comment: have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450336/how-to-set-color-for-selected-text-in-java

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the `repaint();` method